# How to understand a Lookup table in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am reading through Jeff Duntemann's amazing assembly book and i am stuck with one piece of code for days.

The idea is to “look up” a character in the Digits table using a memory reference:” **Can Anyone dissect the following piece of code and explain it in goofy details ?**

```
 mov al,byte [Digits+eax]   ; Look up the char equivalent of nibble

 Digits:    db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Please see complete source code below:

```
SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data

    BUFFLEN equ 16      ; We read the file 16 bytes at a time
    Buff:   resb BUFFLEN    ; Text buffer itself

SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data

    HexStr: db " 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00",10
    HEXLEN equ $-HexStr     
    Digits: db "0123456789ABCDEF"

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code

global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
    nop         ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...

; Read a buffer full of text from stdin:
Read:
    mov eax,3       ; Specify sys_read call
    mov ebx,0       ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Standard Input
    mov ecx,Buff        ; Pass offset of the buffer to read to
    mov edx,BUFFLEN     ; Pass number of bytes to read at one pass
    int 80h         ; Call sys_read to fill the buffer
    mov ebp,eax     ; Save # of bytes read from file for later
    cmp eax,0       ; If eax=0, sys_read reached EOF on stdin
    je Done         ; Jump If Equal (to 0, from compare)

; Set up the registers for the process buffer step:
    mov esi,Buff        ; Place address of file buffer into esi
    mov edi,HexStr      ; Place address of line string into edi
    xor ecx,ecx     ; Clear line string pointer to 0

; Go through the buffer and convert binary values to hex digits:
Scan:
    xor eax,eax     ; Clear eax to 0

; Here we calculate the offset into the line string, which is ecx X 3
    mov edx,ecx     ; Copy the pointer into line string into edx
;   shl edx,1       ; Multiply pointer by 2 using left shift
;   add edx,ecx     ; Complete the multiplication X3
    lea edx,[edx*2+edx]
; Get a character from the buffer and put it in both eax and ebx:
    mov al,byte [esi+ecx]   ; Put a byte from the input buffer into al
    mov ebx,eax     ; Duplicate the byte in bl for second nybble

; Look up low nybble character and insert it into the string:
    and al,0Fh         ; Mask out all but the low nybble
    mov al,byte [Digits+eax]   ; Look up the char equivalent of nybble
    mov byte [HexStr+edx+2],al ; Write the char equivalent to line string

; Look up high nybble character and insert it into the string:
    shr bl,4        ; Shift high 4 bits of char into low 4 bits
    mov bl,byte [Digits+ebx] ; Look up char equivalent of nybble
    mov byte [HexStr+edx+1],bl ; Write the char equivalent to line string

; Bump the buffer pointer to the next character and see if we're done:
    inc ecx     ; Increment line string pointer
    cmp ecx,ebp ; Compare to the number of characters in the buffer
    jna Scan    ; Loop back if ecx is <= number of chars in buffer

; Write the line of hexadecimal values to stdout:
    mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard output
    mov ecx,HexStr      ; Pass offset of line string
    mov edx,HEXLEN      ; Pass size of the line string
    int 80h         ; Make kernel call to display line string
    jmp Read        ; Loop back and load file buffer again

; All done! Let's end this party:
Done:
    mov eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
    mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero 
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary: this code translates a string of up to 15 characters(without overflow, last char is always `0x0A`) to the hexadecimal representation of its ASCII values.

The position of the input string is kept in `ECX` with a base of `ESI` set in

```
mov esi,Buff        ; Place address of file buffer into esi --- base
mov edi,HexStr      ; Place address of line string into edi
xor ecx,ecx         ; Clear line string pointer to 0        --- pos = 0
```

This position is multiplied by three with

```
lea edx,[edx*2+edx]
```

to get the destination index in `EDI` with base 'HexStr'. Then the current char is loaded to `EAX` (and duplicated to `EBX`) with

```
xor eax,eax             ; Clear eax to 0
; Get a character from the buffer and put it in both eax and ebx:
mov al,byte [esi+ecx]   ; Put a byte from the input buffer into al
mov ebx,eax             ; Duplicate the byte in bl for second nybble
```

After that, the lowest four bits are isolated and replaced according to the `Digits` (Look-up) table by index to get the lower hex digit with

```
; Look up low nybble character and insert it into the string:
and al,0Fh         ; Mask out all but the low nybble
mov al,byte [Digits+eax]   ; Look up the char equivalent of nybble
```

Now `AL` contains the ASCII value of the lower half of the first input byte. Now shift the higher four bits of `BL` to the right by four to get the higher nibble('nybble') and repeat the previous step with `EBX`.

The hex representation of this character is complete. It is written to the result buffer with these two lines

```
mov byte [HexStr+edx+2],al ; Write the char equivalent to line string
mov byte [HexStr+edx+1],bl ; Write the char equivalent to line string
```

`EDX+2` means the rightmost/low nibble of the two char hex value ASCII representation and `EDX+1` the high nibble, respectively. `EDX+0` is the space character between the hex representation (which is skipped).

Now increase the input index in `ECX` and check if it was the last char.

```
; Bump the buffer pointer to the next character and see if we're done:
inc ecx     ; Increment line string pointer
cmp ecx,ebp ; Compare to the number of characters in the buffer
jna Scan    ; Loop back if ecx is <= number of chars in buffer
```

The last char is always `0x0A` if you finish your input by pressing the `RETURN` key, because `sys_read` includes the UNIX line feed character in the result. Finishing the `sys_read` input with `CTRL-D` avoids that (thanks @Peter Cordes).

Comment: re:last line: `read(2)` can easily return with the last character != `\n`, even if input is from a tty in line-buffered canonical mode.  e.g. user types a longer line than the size of the input buffer.  Or user pressed ctrl-d (EOF) after typing a partial line to "submit" it.  (Try it with `cat` with no args, in a terminal).  Also, you should say `sys_read`, definitely not capitalized, if you don't want to say `read(2)`.  The system call number is in `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h` as `__NR_read`

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Thanks for your corrections/additions. I tried to include them in my answer. I think I have sufficiently addressed the overflow issue in the brackets of my first original sentence.

Comment: Nope, on a tty in canonical mode, a `read(2)` will return early on ctrl-d, which isn't "overflow".  A wrong simplification is worse than no simplification, IMO.  You could say that you assume the last char is `\n`, even though it might not be.  Also, I don't think "overflow" is a great word to describe the case when more than a full read-buffer of data is available.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I did not wrote that CTRL-D creates an overflow condition. I just wrote that finishing the input with CTRL-D will avoid the `0x0A` at the end. However, I did refer to the code given which includes `Buff:   resb 16`, limiting the input buffer to 16 bytes including the (possible) Line-Feed-Char. An _overflow_ would likely be tolerated because of section alignment, but this should not be assumed. Also, if you don't like to call the process of exceeding the space of an input buffer an _overflow_, I really wouldn't know how to name a _buffer overflow attack_...

Comment: sorry, forgot to say I was talking about your first-line summary: "without overflow, last char is always 0x0A".

Comment: This is absolutely not a buffer overflow, unless you called `read` with a size > 16.  A buffer overflow is when data is written outside the buffer.  This is a case of unexpected data *inside* the buffer.  The extra data is still sitting in a kernel buffer waiting for the next `read(2)` call, not scribbled over something else in your process's memory space.

Answer (score 8):

There's not much to it. `Digits` is an array of 16 characters, each representing a hexadecimal digit. At the point where `mov al,byte [Digits+eax]` is performed, `eax` contains a value in the range 0..15 (this is ensured by the `xor eax,eax` and `and al,0Fh`), so it reads the character at the corresponding index in `Digits`.

It's essentially the same as if you had written this in C:

```
char Digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
al = Digits[eax];
```